# MySQL with Docker/Kubernetes

Tags: mysql, docker, kubernetes

I am trying to deploy a MySQL Docker Image to Kubernetes. I mostly managed all tasks, Docker Image up and running in Docker, one final thing is missing from Kubernetes deployment.

MySQL has one configuration which is stating which user can log on from which Host 'MYSQL_ROOT_HOST' to configure that for Docker is no problem, Docker Networking is using '172.17.0.1' for bridging.

The problem with Kubernetes, this must be the IP of the Pod trying to connect MySQL Pod and every time a Pod starts, this IP changes.

I try to put the Label of the Pod connecting to the MySQL Pod but it is still looking the IP of the Pod instead of DNS name.

Do you have an idea how I can overcome this problem, I can't even figure out how this should work if I set AutoScaling for the Pod that is trying to connect MySQL, replicas will all have a different IP.

Thx for answers....

Comment: I wonder if it it would work with localhost (https://github.com/Yolean/kubernetes-mysql-cluster/blob/master/50mariadb.yml#L70). I can't find anything about this in the helm chart for mysql (https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/mysql). Perhaps that chart isn't allowing for accessing as the root user from outside (meaning you'd have to kubectl exec in first). If you are open to using helm it would be interesting to see if you can do what you want to do with that chart (possibly with plugging your image into the chart with --set if you've a custom image).

Comment: Use a Service: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/

Comment: 'MYSQL_ROOT_HOST' setting is internal for MySql and it has nothing to do with Kubernetes Services.

Answer (score 0):

As @RyanDowson and @siloko mentioned, you should use Service, Ingress or Helm Charts for these purposes.

Additional information you can find on [Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service), [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress) and [Helm Charts](https://github.com/helm/charts) pages.